# MIPS - Not returning the expected result

Tags: assembly, mips

I just start to study MIPS, and I am trying to translate a recursive program written in C to MIPS and I have encountered some problems.

The program in C is as follow:

```
int calculate (int n, int k){
  int b;
  b = k+2;
  if (n == 0)
     b = 10;
  else
     b = b + 8*n + calculate (n-1,k+1);
  return b*k;

}
```

This is my program that I wrote in MIPS:

```
main:

addi $a0,$0,2
addi $a1,$0,3

jal calculate
addi $t3,$v0,0
li $v0,10
syscall

calculate:
    #a0 = n, a1 = k, t0 = b
    addiu $sp,$sp,-12
    sw $a0,0($sp) # save a0 to stack
    sw $a1,4($sp) # save a1 to stack
    sw $ra,8($sp) # save return address to stack
    
    # Base case
    bne $a0,$0,else # n!=0
    li $t0,10 # b = 10
    mul $v0,$t0,$a1 # v0 = b*k
    j return # Go to Return
else:
    addi $a0,$a0,-1 # n - 1
    addi $a1,$a1,1 # k + 1
    jal calculate
    add $t0,$t0,$v0 # b += calculate(n-1,k+1)
    lw $a0,0($sp)  # Retrive the original n
    lw $a1,4($sp) # Retrieve the original k
    addi $t0,$a1,2 # b += k+2
    li $t1,8 # load 8 as constant
    mul $t1, $t1,$a0 # 8*n
    add $t0,$t0,$t1 # b = b + 8*n
    mul $v0,$t0,$a1 # v0 = b*k
    
return:
    lw $a0,0($sp) # retrive a0 from stack
    lw $a1,4($sp) # retreive a1 from stack
    lw $ra,8($sp) # retrive return address to stack
    addiu $sp,$sp,12
    jr $ra
```

I am using the MARS simulator, and it shows me that my result register $t3, has a value of 0x384 which is 900 in decimal. When I run the program in C, the result is 831.

However everything seems fine to me, and I feel that my program should be running correctly

And is there any other problems with my program? Writing recursive program in MIPS is indeed a bit complicated for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are computing the k+2+8*n before the (recursive) call, which is fine in theory — but not ok to leave the result in `$t0` across a call as it will be wiped out by the call.

You have two options:

- Save `$t0` (after computing that subexpression and) before the call, and restore it after.
  If you do this, you'll need another word of stack space (but you also don't really need to save `n` (`$a0`) then, since it is not used after the call).
- Compute k+2+8*n after the call, which won't require an extra word of stack space, though that will make use of the saved `n` (`$a0`) after the call.

---

When you save argument registers in prolog as you are, they don't need to be restored in the epilogue, so only need to restore `$ra` for the return.

Use `addiu` for your stack allocation/deallocation.  Address arithmetic should be done using unsigned.  (Note the only difference between `addi` and `addiu` is that `addi` checks for overflow in signed arithmetic, which we don't want for addresses b/c they are unsigned.)

---

In your latest edit:

```
jal calculate
add $t0,$t0,$v0 # b += calculate(n-1,k+1)  #### $t0 not good to source here
lw $a0,0($sp)  # Retrive the original n
lw $a1,4($sp) # Retrieve the original k
addi $t0,$a1,2 # b += k+2
```

Suggest doing `b = k+2` first:

```
jal calculate
lw $a0,0($sp)   # Retrive the original n
lw $a1,4($sp)   # Retrieve the original k
addi $t0,$a1,2  # b = k+2                  ##### b=k+2 do that first
add $t0,$t0,$v0 # b += calculate(n-1,k+1)  ##### now  b +=  will work
```

Comment: Sorry I have edited your answer and I just realized it is my fault.